# interface for generic method after method implemented

Tags: java, oop, java-8

The current situation I have is:

- I have 2 maven modules
- module 1 in general with interfaces
- module 2 with implementations and has a particular dependency of a different maven module module3 (external project module)
- module 2 has dependency of module1
- module 1 is not allowed to have dependency of module3
- In module 2 I have a method that implements an interface inherited form a maven artifact which I can not change
- I need to provide a interface with the signature of the method in module1, that I have implemented already implemented in module2, obviously to have other specify implementation for that specific method signature.

the method signature implemented in module2 looks like:

```
 Class MyClass{
   public <T extends Enum<T> & Interface1> Interface2 myMethod(param1, param2...){.....}
}
```

Interface1 and Interface2 are part of module3 (the one I can not modify and module1 cannot have it as dependency)

The question is:
How I can create an interface in module1 to be implemented by MyClass form module 2 with the needed method signature?

Something like:

Module1:

```
interface MyInterface{
 <T extends Enum<T> & -->What I should put here<--- > -->What I should put here<--- myMethod(param1, param2...){.....}
}


 class MyClass implements MyInterface{
   public <T extends Enum<T> & Interface1> Interface2 myMethod(param1, param2...){.....}
}

     class MyClass2 implements MyInterface{
   public <T extends Enum<T> & -->Different interface needed here than Interface1<-- > -->Different interface needed here than Interface2<-- myMethod(param1, param2...){.....}
}
```

Any ideas?
how I can overcome the interfaces inherited from module3 (which I can not change and can not have it as dependence in module1, only in module2 i can have it as dependence)
Basically to provide a more generic interface method signature definition in module1 to satisfy the signature of the method in module2?

Currently it says: both methods: the interface method and the class implemented method have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other.

Comment: If module 1 cannot know about `Interface1`, why would module 1 *need* to restrict `T` to be an `Interface1`? Why would `<T extends Enum<T>>` not be good enough, for module 1?

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to define the desired interface in module 1, and implement it in module 2 by calling the method you cannot modify? Its an intermediate step but allows you to respect both interfaces.

Comment: @Andreas it does not need to restrict it only needs to provide a method signature to satisfy the definition of the method already implemented in module2 and other possible implementations. The biggest problem here are the Interface1 and Interface2 from module3

Comment: @CristianRamon-Cortes the method from module2 I can modify but 1 implementation needs to satisfy the Interface1 and interface2 restriction and the second implementation should not have anything to do with those 2 Interfaces. The solution should be to have a more generic interface which is extended by Interface1 and Interface2. The Implementation 1 to stay with those 2 interfaces limitation and second implementation to implement the more generic interface. But i cant modify module3 to add this more generic interface.

Answer (score 0):

Use inference:

```
 <A, B, T extends Enum<T> & A> B myMethod(param1, param2...){.....}
```

And let the call site figure it out.

---

IMHO when things get this gnarly, generics is over-rated.